# Reach static files under application within website using IIS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, master-pages, virtual-path

I have multiple ASP.NET apps deployed within the Default Web Site in IIS (8). Their virtual directories set up like: App1, App2, so I reach them as localhost/App1/... , localhost/App2/... , they work well.

I want to load a javascript file like below in the masterpage file in the header tag in one of my apps:

```
<script src="/Script/myfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I open the page, I get errors in the console as my files cannot be found, because it search for the file at `localhost/Script/` instead of `localhost/App1/Script/`

Is there a way to set the root directory to be the app's root directory containing the virtual path to the app?

I don't want to hardcore the `/App1` string to the begin of the js files path, because the app is deployed more times, with different Application names under different websites, and I have many js files too.

With the example below, I had also no success:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Script/myfile.js") %>"></script>
```

But if I changed the `<%# %> tag to <%= %>` , then it worked on some page, but anothers threw error: 
"Only content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains content controls". For this error, I found a solution to change the `<%= %>` to `<%# %>` , which not worked for me, it made my js files not working again on any page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution using the code below works (it's in my masterpage's head tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Script/myfile.js") %>"></script>
```

But I need to put the code below into the masterpage's pageload method:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
        this.Page.DataBind();
```

Without this, the file won't be loaded, that's why it didn't work for me for the first time.

Hope it helps someone.